# Youtube API v3 (PHP) - Any way to get a YouTube video content rating?

Tags: php, youtube-api

Is there any way to get a YouTube video content rating?

For example the ratings shown here:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/146399?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API it seems so https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Ratings:

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
  },
```

And also content ratings:

```
contentRating": {
      "mpaaRating": string,
      "tvpgRating": string,
      "bbfcRating": string,
      "chvrsRating": string,
      "eirinRating": string,
      "cbfcRating": string,
      "fmocRating": string,
      "icaaRating": string,
      "acbRating": string,
      "oflcRating": string,
      "fskRating": string,
      "kmrbRating": string,
      "djctqRating": string,
      "russiaRating": string,
      "rtcRating": string,
      "ytRating": string
    }
```